# Как сменить прокси сервер через cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, proxy

Например, был `92.125.644.5:80`, а поставить `97.352.0.3:80`. Или как через реестр можно поменять?

Comment: Сразу встаёт доп. вопрос -- поменять для чего? Для IE, пользователь Вася, для Opera, пользователь Вася или ещё для чего/кого?

Comment: Как прописать этот NETSH если нужно кроме сервера с портом указать ещё логин с паролем?

Answer (score 6):

Видимо речь идёт о NETSH
Вот что нагуглил [для win7](http://wintech.net.ru/windows-7/win7-admin/677-nastroyka-sistemnogo-proksi-v-windows-7.html), для более ранних версий Windows может не работать.

```
netsh winhttp show proxy  
netsh winhttp set proxy 97.352.0.3:80  
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

Answer (score 4):

Регфайл для IE

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyServer"="97.352.0.3:80"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyServer"="97.352.0.3:80"
```

Первая ветка для текущего пользователя, вторая по-умолчанию для новых пользователей.